# I lost the down arrow icon for the "Next Change" in my VSCode toolbar -- how do I get it back?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My git diff window in VSCode used to show an up-arrow icon (Previous Change) and a down-arrow icon (Next Change) in the toolbar.

I somehow recently lost just the down-arrow, and I can't figure out how to get it back.  The "Next Change" action now instead shows up only in the "More Actions..." menu (see screenshot).

Any suggestions how to fix this?  I have scoured the VSCode settings but have not been able to find anything related.

This screenshot below shows where the arrow used to be:

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: Can you show the example when they're missing?

Comment: Yes it is in the screenshot above.  You can see the up-arrow there in the toolbar but not the down-arrow (which used to be immediately to the right of it).

Comment: So right - This has been bugging me cause I accidentally "removed" the button by dragging it off the toolbar - searched the settings high and low to no avail. Certainly not intuitive. Well done on finding the solution. Would never have thought it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was weirdly hard to figure this out, but the answer turned out to be embarrassingly simple.  Right-clicking on any icon in the toolbar displays a list of icons to show or hide.

[image: vscode snapshot]